# BERT transformer KeyError: 3

Tags: python, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, keyerror, transformer-model

I am quite new to the BERT language model. I am currently using the Huggingface transformer libraryand i'm  encountering an error when encoding the inputs. The goal of the model is to classify fake news.

First I downloaded the dataset which I turned into a pandas dataframe containing 3 columns. Index, tweet, label. The pretrained auto tokenizer from bert large uncased is used to encode the input.

```
TOKENIZER = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-large-uncased")
```

The following function is used:

```
def bert_encode(data,maximum_len) :
input_ids = []
attention_masks = []


for i in range(len(data.tweet)):
    encoded = TOKENIZER.encode_plus(data.tweet[i],
                                    add_special_tokens=True,
                                    max_length=maximum_len,
                                    pad_to_max_length=True,
                                    return_attention_mask=True,
                                    truncation=True)
  
    input_ids.append(encoded['input_ids'])
    attention_masks.append(encoded['attention_mask'])
    
return np.array(input_ids),np.array(attention_masks)
```

The function is applied to the the data to get the train input id and the attention masks:

```
train_input_ids,train_attention_masks = bert_encode(train,600)
test_input_ids,test_attention_masks = bert_encode(test,600)
```

However, calling the function gives me the following error: KeyError: 3
Provided beolow is the exact error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 3

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 3
```

Any insight on how to debug are welcome.

Comment: Can you cast `data.tweet[i]` to list and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Print the index using:
`train.index` and `test.index`

Sometimes, the index is not sequential since you may have combined tables from different sources. You can fix this by typing

`train.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

`test.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

If you need to keep the original index for `train` and `test`, do this step before splitting into `train` and `test`.